# Let $A, B$ be sets. Prove that $A \cap B = A$ iff $A \cup B = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B$ be sets. Prove that $A \cap B = A$ iff $A \cup B = B$.

My current progress:
$\Rightarrow$:
Suppose $A \cap B = A$,
Let $x \in A$ be an arbitrary element.
Based on the above assumption, we have $x \in B$ and therefore $x \in A ∪ B$

Please advise on how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cup B$ regardless of any assumption on $A$, $B$ or anything else.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: edited to fix statement

Comment: Prove that both conditions are equivalent with $\;A\subset B\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

If $A\cap B=A$ then $A\subset B$, and thus $A\cup B=B$. Conversely, if $A\cup B=B$ then $B\supset A$ and thus $A\cap B=A$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A=A\cap B$ we have: $x\in A \implies x\in A\cap B\implies x\in B$.

So if $x\in A\cup B$ we have $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. But $x\in A\implies x\in B$.

So $x\in A\cup B\implies x\in B$. So $A\cup B=B$

Comment: Do u know how to prove the converse also? Meaning proving that if (A ∪ B ) = B then A ∩ B

Comment: and i do not really understand  'So if x∈A∪Bx∈A∪B we have x∈Ax∈A or x∈Bx∈B. But x∈A⟹x∈Bx∈A⟹x∈B.' would you mind explaining it for me? Thankssss!!!